# Sum of all real numbers $x$ such that $(\text{A quadratic})^\text{Another quadratic}=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the sum of all real numbers $x$ such that
>   $(x^2-5x+5)^{(x^2-7x+12)}=1$?

So I know that $x^0=1$ and $1^x=1$. So, I can solve for them and find $x$, and add them up.

Solving $x^2-7x+12=0$ for $x^0=1$ gives $x=3, 4$.

Solving $x^2-5x+5=1$ for $1^x=1$ gives $x=1, 4$.

Adding them up gives $1+3+4=8$.

This is wrong. What did I do wrong? Did I miss a case? If so, what case have I missed?

Thanks!

Max0815

Comment: No you don't.  When you put $x=4$ you get $1^0$.  The $0^0$ ambiguity is not the OP's problem here, see the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint

You have missed $$(-1)^{\text{even number}}=1$$

Now if $x^2-5x+5=-1,x=?$

Which values of $x$ make the exponent even?

Comment: Oh! I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: @lab check my edit.  I wanted to clarify that we can have _any_ even exponent on $-1$.  The words are rendered by using \text{words} between the dollar signs.

Comment: @Oscar, Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

Three cases:
$$x^0=1$$
$$1^x=1$$
$$(-1)^{\text{even #}}=1$$
Substituting into the original equation gives $$x=3, 4$$ $$x=1, 4$$ $$x=2, 3$$
We don't add in the solutions already accounted for, namely, 3 and 4.
$\sum=3+4+1+2=10$.