# Sum of all values that satisfy $\frac{x^{x-3}}{x}=\frac{x}{x^\frac{4}{x}}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the sum of all values of $x$ that satisfy the equation
>   $\frac{x^{x-3}}{x}=\frac{x}{x^\frac{4}{x}}$?

I start off by cross multiplying.

$$x^2=x^{x-3+\frac{4}{x}}$$

Taking the square root of both sides gives me:

$$x=\pm x^{\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{2x}}$$

I start with the positive side first:

$$1=\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{2x}$$$$x^2-5x+4=0$$$$x=4, 1$$

Now, I start with the negative side:

$$x=-x^{\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{2x}}$$$$x^\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}=-1$$

I can't log both sides because of the $-1$, so I raise both sides by a power of $2x$ to get rid of the fraction. Because $2x$ is even, the RHS becomes a $1$.

$$x^{x^2-5x+4}=1$$

Now, taking the log of both sides, I have

$$(x^2-5x+4)\cdot\operatorname{log}(x)=0$$

Dividing both sides by $\operatorname{log}(x)$, I get $x^2-5x+4=0$ again, which should give me $x=4, 1$ again. So thus, the answer should be $4+1=5$.

However, this is wrong, as the answer key says that the answer is $-1+1+4=\boxed{4}$. **I have checked $-1$ as a solution on all of my equations, and all of them work. How can I derive the $-1$ out from my equations? Or, if my approach or any of my equations are wrong, how do I get the answer $x=-1$?**

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157637/sum-of-all-real-numbers-x-such-that-texta-quadratic-textanother-quadra

Comment: This is a good question. In fact if you draw the 2 curves, x=-1 does not show as an intersection point !!!

Comment: Technically it does.  While continuous curves can be rendered only in the first quadrant, the functions over $\mathbb{R}$ also include other individual points where they may be defined.  One such point for both functions is $x=-1$, and at that value of $x$ the points are the same for the two functions.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, thank your for your comment. I am still not clear why would a program not plot the said curves at x=-1 if the function is defined at x=-1?

Comment: @OscarLanzi, thank your for your comment. I was not aware of the relationship between zeroes, algebraic operations and continuity of the function....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning here is faulty:

> I can't log both sides because of the $-1$, so I raise both sides by a power of $2x$ to get rid of the fraction. Because $2x$ is even, the RHS becomes a $1$.

For one thing, what if $x$ is not an integer, and $2x$ is not even?

Starting from $x^\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}=-1$, you could absolute value both sides: $$\lvert x\rvert^\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}=1$$
and then take the logarithm: $$\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}\ln\lvert x\rvert=0$$ from which you conclude either $x=4$, $x=1$, or $\lvert x\rvert=1$. Check that $4$, $1$, and $-1$ satisfy the original equation, and you have a complete solution.

Comment: Hey, a quick question. When you absolute value both sides, why is only the $x$ absolute valued in the LHS, shouldn't it be the whole LHS? Could you explain why?

Comment: @Max0815 if a number is positive, all real exponents of that number will he positive too. Technically, he should have put it around the exponent, but it's really not necessary and in some cases may cause extra confusion. Thats what I think at least

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $a^b$ makes sense, then $\left\lvert a^b\right\rvert=\lvert a\rvert^b$.

Answer (score 2):

In your second case, after you render

$x^{\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}}=-1$

forget about logarithms.  Taking absolute values of the equation $a^b=-1$ and remembering that anything to a zero power can only be $+1$, conclude that the only way to get a value of $-1$ using real variables is to have $a=x=-1$.  So put $x=-1$ into the equation you derived and see whether, in fact, it's consistent with the power having a value of $-1$.

Comment: I see, because no number to any power except (-1) to an odd power gives a value of -1... +1

Answer (score 1):

I start off by cross multiplying.

$$x^2=x^{x-3+\frac{4}{x}}$$

Taking the square root of both sides gives me:

$$x=\pm x^{\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{2x}}$$

I start with the positive side first:

$$1=\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{2x}$$$$x^2-5x+4=0$$$$x=\boxed{4}, \boxed{1}$$

Now, I start with the negative side:

$$x=-x^{\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{2x}}$$$$x^\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}=-1$$

Absolute value-ing both sides gives $$\lvert x^\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}\rvert=\lvert -1\rvert$$

Now, we use the property that $\lvert x^y\rvert=\lvert x\rvert^y$ to get $$\lvert x\rvert^\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}=1$$

Logging both sides gives:

$$\operatorname{log}\lvert x\rvert^\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}=\log1$$$$\frac{x^2-5x+4}{2x}\cdot\operatorname{log}\lvert x\rvert=0$$$$\frac{\operatorname{log}\lvert x\rvert\cdot (x^2-5x+4)}{2x}=0$$

Solving for $\operatorname{log}\lvert x\rvert$(multiplying by $2x$ and dividing by $x^2-5x+4$) gives:$$\operatorname{log}\lvert x\rvert\cdot (x^2-5x+4)=0$$$$\operatorname{log}\lvert x\rvert=0$$

Now, solving for $x$ gives:
$$10^{\operatorname{log}\lvert x\rvert}=10^0$$$$\lvert x\rvert=1$$$$x=\boxed{\pm1}$$

So the three solutions are $x=-1, 1, 4$ which gives $-1+1+4=\boxed{4}$

Comment: Step 2 above is KEY. Does multiplying by $x^{-1}$ result in the same magnitude with different signs? I think so but I guess you need to emphasis on this if it is a concrete rule.

Comment: @NoChance thank you for reminding me. I didn’t see that until my dad reminded me.