# Solving $\sin (x )^{\sin(2x) - \cos(2x)} = 1$ where $0^{\circ}<x<360^{\circ}$.

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin (x )^{\sin(2x) - \cos(2x)} = 1,\quad 0^{\circ}<x<360^{\circ}.$$

Answers are given but working is not found - please help me with this question. Thank you

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157637/sum-of-all-real-numbers-x-such-that-texta-quadratic-textanother-quadra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $x^y=1$ then $x=1$ or $y=0$ AND $x\ne0$. This follows from taking logs both sides:
$$y\ln{(x)}=0$$

Comment: Also in general, $x$ could be $-1$ and $y$ an even integer.

Comment: I understand that y can be 0 with the logaritms law...but how do we solve for x when x=1?

Comment: @manusakthinatarajan $x^y=1\implies|x|^y=1$, now take the logarithm. $y\ln|x|=0\implies y=0\vee|x|=1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: After taking logarithms, note that

$$(\sin 2x - \cos 2x) \cdot \log (\sin x) = \log 1$$

Thus $$(\sin 2x - \cos 2x) = 0$$ or $$\log (\sin x) = 0$$

as $\log 1 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. It answers my question.